# How do I divide two numbers in assembly without using the MUL or DIV operators?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am working on something that will divide two numbers in assembly without using the MUL or DIV operators.  The logic is, if n*var < x, where x is the number to divide and var is the number to divide by, increment n by 1 and repeat.  So in the event of there being a remainder, the divider will round up the answer by 1.

First, I created a multiplier that takes advantage of bit shifting, and this works.

```
//multiply
int ans, var1;
_asm {
        mov eax, 00001111b; A = 1111
        mov ebx, 00001010b; B = 1010
        mov var1, 00000001b; C = 0001
        mov ecx, 0;
        shl ebx, 3; shift b register left by 3
    L1:
        cmp ecx, 4; check if multiplication is done
            je L4; go to empty loop
        inc ecx; increment counter by 1
        AND var1, eax; check if the least significant bit is 1
        cmp var1, 1; checks if var1 is = 1
            je L2;
        cmp var1, 0; check if var1 = 0
            je L3;
    L2:
        shr eax, 1; shift a register right 1 bit
        add eax, ebx; add a and b registers
        jmp L1; go back to L1
    L3:
        shr eax, 1;
        jmp L1; go back to L1
    L4 :
        mov ans, eax; move eax to answer
};
cout << "Multiply 00001111 and 00001010" << endl << ans << endl;
```

So what I am trying to do is implement this multiplier with two more loops:  one that increments n and sets the registers to the correct numbers to multiply, and one that checks if n*var >= x.  If n*var < x, it will go to increment n and set the registers to multiply, then multiply them out.  After the answer is found, the incremented register (edx) is but into variable d and output to the console.

There is something wrong in this program that I'm not seeing, and somehow, the answer always turns out to be var2*16, where var2 is the number to divide.

```
int var1;
int var2;
int var3;
int d;
_asm {
    ; if n*var3 < var2, increment n and repeat
    mov var2, 12; number to be divided
    mov var3, 5; number to divide with
    mov ecx, 0;
    mov edx, 0; number to increment
L11 :
    cmp eax, var2;
    js L12; if n*n < var2, increment n and multiply.
    cmp eax, var2
    jns L16; answer found, jump to empty loop       
L12 :
    inc edx
    mov eax, edx
    mov ebx, var3
    shl ebx, 3
    mov ecx, 0
    jmp L13
L13 :
    cmp ecx, 4; check if multiplication is done
    je L11;
    inc ecx; increment counter by 1
    AND var1, eax; check if the least significant bit is 1
    cmp var1, 1; checks if var1 is = 1
    je L14;
    cmp var1, 0; check if var1 = 0
    je L15;
L14:
    shr eax, 1; shift a register right 1 bit
    add eax, ebx; add a and b registers
    jmp L13; go back to L1
L15 :
    shr eax, 1;
    jmp L13;
L16:
    mov d, edx
};
cout << "The quotient is " << d << endl;
```

I'm also creating a very similar program that calculates the square root of a number, where if n*n < x, where x is the number to take the square root of, increment n and repeat.  Solving this bug with the divider should also help me with the square root program, where the same bug is occuring.

I've been stuck on this for a few days, and I cannot figure out what is wrong that's causing this strange bug.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code and see where it doesn't do what you want it to.

Comment: Some time ago I coded a small polish notated calculator in plain asm. It worked, at least for integers. Nevertheless, the results of integer devision are also decimals, this also seemed to work. As long as You know, that division is repeated subtraction, You could do it by using sub. I did that this way.

Comment: In second code block: what is `eax` at the first time going by `L11:`? Looks undefined to me. Plus doing the same `cmp` twice with `js/jns` is wasting CPU cycles. After first `cmp + js` instruction pair you don't need to do `cmp` again, as the flags are still set from previous (then `js` does not modify flags) and the `jns` will happen in 100% of cases, as all SF=1 cases were already picked up by previous `js`. ... I did check only those ~10 lines of second block, as I was curious if you *really* do `++n` and then multiplying `n*var` AGAIN, OMG :D .. ridiculous. `(n+1)*var == (n*var)+var`!

Comment: Your multiplier is broken. It works only when a is one less than a power of two. Your test case happens to be one of the lucky values which is why you didn't notice.

Comment: There is a more efficient square root algorithm which rather than trying *every possible value* starts with the square root as `0` and tries setting one bit at a time, from the highest possible bit downward. If the square of this test value is <= target, you keep that bit set, and move to the next bit. For example, the square root of a 32-bit unsigned number has maximum 16 bits, so the first trial would be `0x8000`, and the next trial would be `0xC000` or `0x0400` depending on the result of the first trial, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Subtractions can be the answer to your question ("How do I divide two numbers in assembly without using the MUL or DIV operators?"), example (tested on VS2013) :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    int dividend;
    cout << "Enter DIVIDEND : "; //◄■ EXAMPLE : 23.
    cin >> dividend;

    int divisor;
    cout << "Enter DIVISOR : "; //◄■ EXAMPLE : 4.
    cin >> divisor;

    int quotient = 0;
    _asm {
            mov eax, dividend
        divisions:
            cmp eax, divisor
            jb  finish        //◄■ IF DIVIDEND < DIVISOR
            sub eax, divisor  //◄■ DIVIDEND - DIVISOR. EXAMPLE :  23 - 4.
            inc quotient      //◄■ DIVISIONS COUNTER.
            jmp divisions
        finish:
    }
    cout << "The result is " << quotient; //◄■ EXAMPLE : 5
    return 0;
}
```

Previous code will throw integer result. If you want the result with decimals it will be necessary to multiply the last dividend (3 in previous example) by 10 for one decimal or by 100 for two decimals (or 1000 for three decimals, and so on), example (tested on VS2013) :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    int dividend;
    cout << "Enter DIVIDEND : "; //◄■ EXAMPLE : 23.
    cin >> dividend;

    int divisor;
    cout << "Enter DIVISOR : "; //◄■ EXAMPLE : 4.
    cin >> divisor;

// ▼ CALCULATE QUOTIENT.
    int quotient = 0;
    _asm {
            mov eax, dividend
        divisions:
            cmp eax, divisor
            jb  finish1       //◄■ IF DIVIDEND < DIVISOR
            sub eax, divisor  //◄■ DIVIDEND - DIVISOR. EXAMPLE :  23 - 4.
            inc quotient      //◄■ DIVISIONS COUNTER.
            jmp divisions
        finish1:
            mov dividend, eax //◄■ LAST DIVIDEND (USED FOR REMAINDER). EXAMPLE : 3.
    }

// ▼ CALCULATE REMAINDER WITH TWO DECIMALS.
    int remainder = 0;
    _asm {
        // ▼ MULTIPLY LAST DIVIDEND BY 100. EXAMPLE : 3 * 100 = 300.
            mov ecx, 100  //◄■ REPEAT 100 TIMES.
            mov eax, 0
        multiply:
            add eax, dividend //◄■ MULTIPLY IS A SERIES OF ADDITIONS. EXAMPLE : EAX + 3.
            loop multiply
        // ▼ GET REMAINDER WITH TWO DECIMALS.
        decimals:
            cmp eax, divisor
            jb  finish2  //◄■ IF DIVIDEND < DIVISOR
            sub eax, divisor  //◄■ DIVIDEND - DIVISOR. EXAMPLE : 300 - 4.
            inc remainder //◄■ DIVISIONS COUNTER.
            jmp decimals
        finish2:
    }
    cout << "The result is " << quotient <<  "." << remainder; //◄■ EXAMPLE : 5.75
    return 0;
}
```